# What does an overlong bitshift on a LLVM vector yield?

Tags: llvm, undefined-behavior, llvm-ir

The [LLVM documentation for 'shl'](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#shl-instruction) says that

```
<result> = shl i32 1, 32
```

is an [undefined value](http://llvm.org/docs/LangRef.html#undefined-values) because it's shifting by greater than or equal to the number of bits in an `i32`. However, it's not clear to me what happens with

```
<result> = shl <2 x i32> < i32 1, i32 1>, < i32 1, i32 32>
```

Is only the second element of the result undefined (`result=<2 x i32> < i32 2, i32 undef>`), or is the result as a whole undefined (`result=<2 x i32> undef`)?